# Slow query performance postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I have a database consisting of two tables: corr1, corr1_2. Both these tables has two columns each: c1 and c2 and every column contains 100k rows of data. The data is integers drawn from a normal distribution. The data is highly correlated:

- corr1.c1 has a min value of 353, max value of 651 and 271 unique values
- corr1.c2 has a min value of 540, max value of 852 and 266 unique values
- corr1_2.c1 has a min value of 452, max value of 750 and 273 unique values
- corr1_2.c2 has a min value of 562, max value of 849 and 265 unique values

The problem is that the query performance is extremely slow for demanding queries. The following query is extremely slow:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM corr1, corr1_2 WHERE corr1.c1 > 500 AND corr1_2.c2 > 570;
```

I've created indexes for the tables according to:

```
CREATE INDEX corr1_c1_idx ON public.corr1 USING btree (c1)
CREATE INDEX corr1_c2_idx ON public.corr1 USING btree (c2)
CREATE INDEX corr1_2_c1_idx ON public.corr1_2 USING btree (c1)
CREATE INDEX corr1_2_c2_idx ON public.corr1_2 USING btree (c2)
```

Do anyone have any idea in how I can improve the performance or is this too demanding for my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't write a join condition, so you are getting a cross join.

You didn't say what mean value and standard deviation are, but it seems like both conditions are not very selective. So you end up with almost 100000 times 100000 result rows.

So it is not surprising that the query is slow.